# Will I be charged if I delete AWS resources in less than an hour?

Tags: amazon-web-services

As per the AWS pricing mechanism they mentioned every where like they charge per hour of resources so if I have to create something for testing and then cleanup before an hour so will it attract any charges or not on monthly bill ?

Comment: Possibility off-topic in Stack Overflow, not programming related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will attract changes on your bill. Take EC2 as an example, according to the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/), you will be billed based on instance usage for per-hour billing instance even if you only used the instance for less than an hour in a month.

> **Q: How will I be charged and billed for my use of Amazon EC2?**
>
> You pay only for what you use. Displayed pricing is an hourly rate but
>   depending on which instances you choose, you pay by the hour or second
>   (minimum of 60 seconds) for each instance type. **Partial instance-hours
>   consumed are billed based on instance usage.** Data transferred between
>   AWS services in different regions will be charged as Internet Data
>   Transfer on both sides of the transfer. Usage for other Amazon Web
>   Services is billed separately from Amazon EC2.

Comment: That's actually not true for everything, as the second based billing is only for a Linux platform: "Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the time an instance is launched until it is terminated or stopped. Each partial instance-hour consumed will be billed per-second for Linux Instances and as a full hour for all other instance types." https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Answer (score 0):

> EC2 usage are billed on one second increments, with a **minimum** of 60 seconds

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

- 1s charges 60s
- 60s charges 60s
- 61s charges 61s

Comment: This is incomplete. Per-second billing is not available for instances running Microsoft Windows or certain Linux distributions that have a separate hourly charge (I believe this means RHEL, SUSE, IBM).